# Woocommerce plugin - How to create two versions of the same plugin with slightly different implementation for different users

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, git

I am working on the development of a woocommerce plugin and this plugin is shipped to 2 different set of customers. I'd like to manage both of those versions in one git repository. But then ship to each customer their version (I send them a zipped folder of the plugin).

**Issue:**
It is a hassle to maintain two versions on two separate git branches and there is no complier for example to apply certain changes based on which version of the plugin I am creating

**Goal:**
I am trying to manage two different versions of a plugin in the same repository

**Methods I've tried:**
Having the files the are different between both versions in separate folders and making an alias in the cmd that I use to copy the files intended for this version before zipping the folder

Comment: Can all files be shipped or are they considered secret? If they can, you can work mostly with interfaces and for each version implement that interface. Then you just need one option (e.g. via WP option configured in wp-admin) that determines if `MyInterfaceImplA` or `MyInterfaceImplB` should be used.

Comment: Preferably, I want to only ship the relevant files to the relevant set of customers